# How to render an image with arabic charachter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to load an url that have some arabic charachters.

```
<nuxt-image fit="cover" placeholder="/temp/imagePlaceholder.png"
                    :alt="title"
                    src="https://peramoon.com/upload/products/انگشتر زمستان ...1.jpg"/>
```

but my nuxt image doesn't load my image. I got this error message:

> Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined

Comment: I think the issue is not image name, please share the whole script

Comment: Please explain more. you can load this image? I'm using nuxt-image library.

Comment: according to [this](https://image.nuxtjs.org/nuxt-image#src) they say *Path to image file. src sould be in form of absolute path and starts with /*

Comment: my sanbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-app-demovue-ssr-forked-pkcv3

@BoussadjraBrahim